# Saving an image to ExtSD in android using Java?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

So after trying many answers for the same question, here are just two e.g;

[Saving an image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988322/saving-an-image-in-android)

and

[Saving an image to a server using a Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878141/android-saving-an-image-to-directory)

My app still fails in fact whatever I have done has made it worse, before it would actually save the image as "temp.jpg" in the ExtSD root folder, now when I click the tick to accept the photo nothing happens, no crashing, no nothing, I can retake the image and I can cancel the taking of a photo but nothing else happens.

What it does now:

1. Opens the camera (or gallery)
2. Takes the photo
3. Fails to save/set the photo

What I want it to do;

1. Take the photo
2. Store it with a unique name (timestamp)
3. Have the image set to `CircleView`

Here is my code (if you need more please ask for what you need);

```
        CircleImageView circleImageView;
    ImageButton b;

    private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take a Pic", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Set Profile Pic");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take a Pic"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    String folder_main = "iDealer";
                    String sub_folder = "ProPics";
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyy_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    String pro_pic_name = folder_main + "_" + timeStamp;
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folder_main + "/" + sub_folder + pro_pic_name);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "iDealer" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                if (c != null) {
                    c.moveToFirst();
                }
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path from gallery = ", picturePath+"");
                circleImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug on onActivityResult()

Comment: change File f = new `File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());` to `File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/label_" + time + ".jpg");`

Comment: time is system timestamp.

Comment: verify permission for read and write first inside menifest file,plus if you are testing on Android 6.0 + device ! ,then you have to set permission runtime.

Comment: You need to add permission in androidmanifest.xml file  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> and you used android 6.0 os device then allow permission from app setting.

Comment: @Hemant My androidmanifest has the correct permissions

Comment: @Karan Mer I will try you snippet now thanks

Comment: Add runtime permission for sdcard read. read following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card, Also check below Marshmallow os.

Comment: @Karen Mer tht code change did nothing at all to change the problem